# Laravel 5.1 - blade gives error when no record exists in eloquent relationship setup

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am building an app and I have an eloquent relationship setup on certain tables.  However, when I pull data from the database and try to display in my form, if the row doesn't exist, I get an error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: /home/vagrant/Code/App/public/resources/views/themes/default/admin/editContractor.blade.php)
```

If the row exists in the database, then the page loads fine without errors.  It's important to note that these fields are optional, so they might not always exist in the pivot table in the database.

Here is the line that seems to be causing the issue:

```
{!! Form::text($rate->field, $user->rates()->where('rate_id', $rate->id)->first()->pivot->value) !!}
```

**How can I get around this problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before echoing the value you can check if it exists

```
{!! Form::text($rate->field, ($user->rates()->where('rate_id', $rate->id)->first()) ? $user->rates()->where('rate_id', $rate->id)->first()->pivot->value : null) !!}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well as far what I am concerned, you should do it somewhat like this:

```
{!! Form::text($rate->field, ($user->rates()->where('rate_id', $rate->id)->first()) or "Your default value") !!}
```

But I do not recommend it do in this way. Instead write a logic in your controller and pass that data to this view.